# Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline Stage View display multiple branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

Is there a way to get a BuildWall like thing with the new multibranch pipelines from Jenkins 2.0? Ideally I want to see all branches of all projects like I had before ( there I had one job per branch per project and was seeing the state of all in the overview ) - now I would have to click on all folders to see the state of all branches - but the Jenkinsfile job setup and automatic branch detection are great - Ideally I want to have the best of both worlds which should be possible as far as I see - just don't know how to do it e.g. if there is a plugin for this already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using the [Build Monitor](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin) plugin with the following
[image]
This gives this result.
[image]

Comment: If I want to remove `fed-oca-pipeline >>` on the dashboard and show only the job name ? 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the Dashboard view of the [Build Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin), you can also expand the Job listing of the folder to include all branches and PRs. I think this is more suitable for "normal" usage (vs. dashboard) in order to get an overview over all jobs/branches.

Therefore, use *Edit View* in the folder and select in the *Job Filters* section the option *Recurse in subfolders*.

This will provide you a view as follows ([live version](https://chef-ci.typo3.org/job/TYPO3-cookbooks/)):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info - upvoted! Just one thing for people that also try to do this: "edit view" is not availbale for "all" view - you have to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to see a build records from multiple branches in a stage view at the multibranch project level. It has been proposed.